# Bar Label font size in ZedGraph

Tags: c#, asp.net, zedgraph

I have a graph in which the Graph bar has a text which will be showing in different languages.Using other languages except English ,the text alignment is not correct.Any way to decrease the font size.
What i have is

```
myCurve = myPane.AddBar("My Curve"), list, Color.Blue);
```

[image]

My Curve Text overlaps if displayed in other langauages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i have used is

```
myCurve.Label.FontSpec = myPane.Legend.FontSpec.Clone();
myCurve.Label.FontSpec.Size = 6;//any font size
```